# How to update models server-side after change client-side?

Tags: javascript, cookies, model, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I am having a hard time understanding a fundamental concept in ReactJs. In my app, which is using server-side and client-side rendering, I have a simple model that consists of a string field containing the user's name:

```
function MemberStore(){

    var member = null;

    function getMember() {
        return member;
    }

    return {
        getMember: getMember
    }
}

module.exports = new MemberStore();
```

This value is passed to the server in a cookie and is updated into the model on the server during `renderToString`:

`ReactDom.renderToString(app({path: path, cookie: cookie}));`

This works great, and the page loads client-side with the appropriate user's name. Now - In my app I have a simple `logout` function that sets the user's name in the model to null client-side and expires the cookie that gets passed to the server. Once again this works great, and my ReactJs components are re-rendered client-side with and empty username and the cookie is removed. The problem is if immediately after logout I reload the page, the server's `MemberStore` model is in its original state with the username even though no cookie is passed in. Why, even after page load, is the server retaining the model from my previous session? Is there something I should be doing to sync the models on the server with the models client-side after changes are made client-side? Thanks!